Flutter Custom Clip
i want to make a container, but with custom shape like an image i given. Can you give me a hint?
and each container can fill with text or icon. Thanks for people to be kind for helping me.
The shape that i want
its kinda one long container, but cut in one third of that container, i hope you guys understand thank you
i'd try with this code , but still not meet my desire
`body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 80,
              height: 200,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(30.0),
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.white, width: 2, style: BorderStyle.solid),
              ),
              child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0),
                child: ClipPath(
                  clipper: CustomClipperExample(),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.white, width: 2, style: BorderStyle.solid),
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white)),
                        Text(
                          'Hewan',
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge,
                        ),
                        IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {},
                            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_forward, color: Colors.white)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),


class CustomClipperExample extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height * 0.2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.2, size.width * 0.2, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width * 0.2, size.height);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.1, size.height * 0.8, 0, size.height * 0.8);
    path.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.2);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipperExample oldClipper) => false;
}`



If you are looking for already developed solution look for this library . You can use transform on this to achieve the required result https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_clippers

Try using this tool to create custom shapes with the CustomPainter class.
It supports converting a given SVG to Flutter code. You can also draw your shapes and get the code free by creating and logging in to an account. I hope this helps you.
https://shapemaker.web.app/
